# Form Validation - Scroll past input box

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, validation

I am creating inquiry form that has required fields. When the user presses the submit button a list of errors is display for the user to correct. This list is a set of labels relating to the required fields and when the user clicks them, they are taken to the relevant input box. The scrolling stops at the input box and doesn't display the actual label of the input.

How do I make it so when the user selects the error input, the website scrolls upwards to include the label input?

Thank you :)

Comment: It's not my place to interfere with your design, but I personally don't like lists of errors. Just mark the invalid ones with red color. To fix the scrolling you simply need to give each input field an id, and upon validation, change the location to that id (happens only once, for the first invalid input field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to subtract something from the top offset of the element you wnat to scroll to example

```
$(".error-massage").click(function(){
    var l = $(this).attr("data-label");
    top_Offset = $("*[label='" + l +"']").offset().top;
    $(window).scrollTop(top_Offset - 100 + "px")
})
```

considering you error massage list is like

```
<ul>
 <li class="error-massage" data-label="name">invalid name </li>
 <li class="error-massage" data-label="pass">invalid pass</li>
 <li class="error-massage" data-label="somthing">invalid somthing</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include an anchor to the ID of the relevant invalid input

```html
<ul>
 <li class="error-massage">
   <a href="#input-name">invalid name</a>
 </li>
 <li class="error-massage">
   <a href="#input-pass">invalid pass</a>
 </li>
 <li class="error-massage">
   <a href="#input-something">invalid something</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

No JS needed.